# Compare SQL Table Rows, return different answers if exact match, 1 difference, 2 differences etc

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a large dataset and its looking like using Access/SQL tables may be the best approach (though even Excel with VBA may be of use). After searching around however nothing had an exact match.

I have something that looks like the table below and want to know in one result whether any of the rows match exactly. I'd also like to know of rows that match except for 1 difference, or 2 differences etc (these could be treated as separate queries).

In the example below for example an output would show that A and B match under an exact match, A and C match with one difference (as do B and C). D has 1 mismatch with B and C but 2 mismatches with A.

To then go one level beyond this, if I wanted simple say does row D (as in user selected as opposed to just scanning the whole database above) have any matches how would the query be adjusted for that?

```css
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Item | Score1 | Score2 | Score3 | Score4 | Score5 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| A    |      1 |      1 |      2 |      1 |      1 |
| B    |      1 |      1 |      2 |      1 |      1 |
| C    |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
| D    |      0 |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: if you column set is small, you can easily put together a few columns of Excel formulas using `=If(And(B2=C2,C2=D2,D2=E2,E2=F2),"Y","")` and so on for all matches, 1 match, 2 matches .... You can also use a vlookup for finding matches down a column.

Comment: The column row is unfortunately large (00's to 000's).

Comment: This is a bit of a mind bender. I think it would help us out if you would provide examples of what your ideal output(s) would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below MS Access query with six `GROUP BY` subqueries which does show which items match across all columns. But for other column differences, query presents a sort of dashboard for users to decide matches.

The concept behind the query is to concatenate all Scores into a string (e.g., 11211, 1111, 01111) and then check character by character (using `Left` and `Mid()` string functions) how many character counts across items are greater than one. Additionally, I had to use an `@` for multiple repeat occurrences.

```
SELECT t1.Item, 
      (t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5) AS StringScores, 

(SELECT 'Yes'  
FROM Scores t2 
WHERE (t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5)=        
      (t2.Score1 & t2.Score2 & t2.Score3 & t2.Score4 & t2.Score5) 
GROUP BY 'Yes', Cstr(t2.Score1 & t2.Score2 & t2.Score3 & t2.Score4 & t2.Score5)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [All Five Scores Match ?], 

(SELECT 'Yes @ ' & Left((t3.Score1 & t3.Score2 & t3.Score3 & t3.Score4 & t3.Score5), 1) 
FROM Scores t3 
WHERE Left((t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5), 1)=        
      Left((t3.Score1 & t3.Score2 & t3.Score3 & t3.Score4 & t3.Score5), 1) 
GROUP BY 'Yes @ ' & Left((t3.Score1 & t3.Score2 & t3.Score3 & t3.Score4 & t3.Score5), 1)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [First Score Matches ?], 

(SELECT 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t4.Score1 & t4.Score2 & t4.Score3 & t4.Score4 & t4.Score5), 2, 1) 
FROM Scores t4 
WHERE Mid((t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5), 2, 1)=        
      Mid((t4.Score1 & t4.Score2 & t4.Score3 & t4.Score4 & t4.Score5), 2, 1) 
GROUP BY 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t4.Score1 & t4.Score2 & t4.Score3 & t4.Score4 & t4.Score5), 2, 1)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [Second Score Matches ?], 

(SELECT 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t5.Score1 & t5.Score2 & t5.Score3 & t5.Score4 & t5.Score5), 3, 1) 
FROM Scores t5 
WHERE Mid((t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5), 3, 1)=        
      Mid((t5.Score1 & t5.Score2 & t5.Score3 & t5.Score4 & t5.Score5), 3, 1) 
GROUP BY 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t5.Score1 & t5.Score2 & t5.Score3 & t5.Score4 & t5.Score5), 3, 1)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [Third Score Matches ?], 

(SELECT 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t6.Score1 & t6.Score2 & t6.Score3 & t6.Score4 & t6.Score5), 4, 1) 
FROM Scores t6 
WHERE Mid((t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5), 4, 1)=       
      Mid((t6.Score1 & t6.Score2 & t6.Score3 & t6.Score4 & t6.Score5), 4, 1) 
GROUP BY 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t6.Score1 & t6.Score2 & t6.Score3 & t6.Score4 & t6.Score5), 4, 1)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [Fourth Score Matches ?], 

(SELECT 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t7.Score1 & t7.Score2 & t7.Score3 & t7.Score4 & t7.Score5), 5, 1) 
FROM Scores t7 
WHERE Mid((t1.Score1 & t1.Score2 & t1.Score3 & t1.Score4 & t1.Score5), 5, 1) =        
      Mid((t7.Score1 & t7.Score2 & t7.Score3 & t7.Score4 & t7.Score5), 5, 1) 
GROUP BY 'Yes @ ' & Mid((t7.Score1 & t7.Score2 & t7.Score3 & t7.Score4 & t7.Score5), 5, 1)  
HAVING Count(*) > 1) AS [Fifth Score Matches ?]

FROM Scores AS t1;
```

Below is the output. As you can see, a user can tell A & B are fully matched across all 5 scores by first column (main takeaway); and C & D match all four scores except very first; C matches first two items A & B on all but third score; D matches first two A & B on all but first and third scores.

[image: Scores Match - Short Output]

And I went ahead and tested on four more possible scores:

[image: Scores Match - Long Output]

Admittedly, these outputs may look like a re-styling of original table but remember only occurrences greater than 1 will appear. You can output this query into a table and filter/sort to see patterns clearer.

Finally, this can be extended if you need checks such as first three scores, last two scores or any combination of multiple scores. Simply add corresponding subquery with `Left(StringScores, 2)` or `Mid(StringScores, 4, 2)` string functions.